# Change alignment of icon and text in custom bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am using "com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationView" for my custom BottomNavigation bar. It works fine but my issue is with alignment of the icon and text in the bottom navigation bar. It aligned horizontally , but i want text to align below the icon. How can I change the alignment?

My XML

```
<com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:active_item_color="@color/colorAccent"
    app:centre_button_color="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:inactive_item_color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:space_background_color="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:centre_button_icon="@drawable/img1"
    app:space_item_icon_size="@dimen/space_item_icon_default_size"
    app:space_item_icon_only_size="@dimen/space_item_icon_only_size"
    app:space_item_text_size="@dimen/space_item_text_default_size"
    app:layout_behavior="com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior"/>
```

In my Activity

```
 spaceNavigationView = (SpaceNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.space);
    spaceNavigationView.initWithSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem("Home", R.drawable.account));
    spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp));
    spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem("Bookings", R.drawable.ic_dashboard_black_24dp));
    spaceNavigationView.addSpaceItem(new SpaceItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp));
    spaceNavigationView.shouldShowFullBadgeText(true);
    spaceNavigationView.setCentreButtonIconColorFilterEnabled(false);
    spaceNavigationView.setSpaceBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    spaceNavigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: you mean this library https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View?

Comment: yes,  implementation 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0' this the implementation i n gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to edit the `space_item_view.xml` layout file, inside the library to solve this problem.

space_item_view.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/space_icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/space_item_icon_default_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/space_item_icon_default_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/space_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/space_icon"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/space_item_text_default_size"
        tools:text="Label One" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/badge_container"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/badge_left_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Go to `SpaceNavigationView.java` class and modify this only.

```
public void showIconOnly(boolean value) {
    isIconOnlyMode = value;
}
```

and in your activity/fragment where you want to implement this simply replace this `spaceNavigationView.showIconOnly();` to `spaceNavigationView.showIconOnly(false);`

found in [this reply](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View/issues/15#issuecomment-380377791)

Comment: I am using this implementation in gradle file, so how can I edit it?

Comment: 1.clone the projec(https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View)t,2. copy **rspacelib** directory to your app. 3. change your gradle like this (https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View/blob/master/Sample/build.gradle)